# Comparison between roots of two polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, recurrence-relations, roots

Let $m,n,p$ be natural number greater than $2$. Consider $$f(x)=(x-p+1)(x-m+1)(x-n+1)-x(2x-m-p+2)$$ We also have $g(x)$ which is obtained by changing $m$ to $m+1$ and $n$ to $n-1$ in $f$,  i.e. $$g(x)=(x-p+1)(x-m)(x-n+2)-x(2x-m-p+1)$$

Let $\alpha_1 \ge \alpha_2 \ge \alpha_3$ be the roots of $f$ and $\beta_1 \ge \beta_2 \ge \beta_3$ be the roots of $g$. How do we prove that $\alpha_1 >\beta_1,\alpha_2 < \beta_2$ and $\alpha_3 >\beta_3$.

Comment: This cannot be true in general. If the statement is true for $(m,n,p)$ then it is false for $(n-1,m+1,p)$.

Comment: We are comparing $(m,n,p)$ with $(m+1,n-1,p)$. So on the same lines $(n-1,m+1,p)$ will be compared with $(n,m,p)$. I don't see how it fails here.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - the symmetry is not what I thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true.

For $m=4,n=3$ and $p=3$, we have $\alpha_1\lt \beta_1$.

*Proof* :

For $m=4,n=3$ and $p=3$, we have
$$f(0)=-12,\quad f(1)=1,\quad f(3)=-3,\quad f(5.7)=0.483$$
$$g(0)=-8,\quad g(1)=4,\quad g(5.7)=-1.217,\quad g(6)=4$$
from which
$$\alpha_1\lt 5.7\lt \beta_1$$
follows.

Comment: Thank you. Quite a fair counter example. But my bad, now I have completely forgotten in which context, $f,g$ came up.